# Java project with maven cannot find resources

Tags: java, maven, nullpointerexception

I'm currently trying to get a file (index.html) from the resource folder, but it always returns null.

Code to load the file:

```
ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

    File file = null;
    try {
        System.out.println(loader.getResource("/public/index.html") + "is the resource");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The files are in the resource folder
[image: Resource folder with files]

[image: jar file with folder]

this is the .jar file with the folder in it. see url at the top of the image)

I have the default pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.bachmann</groupId>
    <artifactId>servertracker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.parse.bolts</groupId>
            <artifactId>bolts-tasks</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.javalin</groupId>
            <artifactId>javalin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that the beginning `/` shouldn't be there.

Comment: @sfat I already tried it without the /, but the same result.

Comment: Is `${project.basedir}/target/classes/public/index.html` exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that your observation happened while testing the code stated in your question.

If so, the problem here is probably that the resources you are trying to load are physically in `src/main/resources`.

Solution: Try moving the `index.html` to `src/test/resources`. Don't forget to mark the directory as a test resources root (if done correctly, your module settings should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfWKA.jpg))